# Mean Line in GNUPlot

Tags: graph, statistics, gnuplot, graphing

I'm trying to get the average response time in my graph of apache requests and response times.

**Sample data:**

```
11/May/2011:17:34:55 2
11/May/2011:17:34:56 38
11/May/2011:17:34:56 2
11/May/2011:17:34:56 493
11/May/2011:17:34:56 2
11/May/2011:17:34:57 281
```

**The data is graphed using this:**

```
plot "input.dat" using 1:2
```

What I want is line in the center of the average response time for every X value.

**Sample Graph:**

http://i.min.us/jlcmbY.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog post](http://hblok.net/blog/posts/2011/04/29/analysing-apache-logs-gnuplot-and-awk/) shows how to analyze access log with moving mean in gnuplot and preprocess data with awk to get totals for every second.

Comment: Thanks! The smooth bezier graph helped too